# Call Code Behind Function from JavaScript (not AJAX!)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have a function on my server side.

```
protected void SelectParticipant(string CompanyId, string EmployeeNumber)
{
    //I do some stuff here.
}
```

I want to call this function from JavaScript on the client side. I've tried searching for it, but all the suggestions I found were for calling a Page Method via AJAX. I don't want that, I want to cause a postback.

```
function MyJSFunction(companyid, employeenumber)
{
    //cause postback and pass the companyid and employee number
    //this is where I need help!
}
```

How can I cause a postback and run a server side function from my JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AddParticipant(companyid, employeenumber)
    {
        $("#AddParticipantPanel").dialog("close");
        var myargs = {CompanyId: companyid, EmployeeNumber: employeenumber};
        var myargs_json = JSON.stringify(myargs);
        __doPostBack('<%= SelectParticipantBtn.UniqueID %>', myargs_json);
    }
</script>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SelectParticipantBtn" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="SelectParticipantBtn_Click" style="display:none;" />
```

And on the server side...

```
/* this is an inner class */
public class SelectParticipantEventArgs
{
    public string CompanyId {get; set;}
    public string EmployeeNumber {get; set;}
}
protected void SelectParticipantBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    string args = Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
    var myargs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SelectParticipantEventArgs>(args);
    string emp_no = myargs.EmployeeNumber;
    string company_id = myargs.CompanyId;
    //do stuff with my arguments
}
```

Instead of using HiddenFields, I used a hidden button. This model works better because I can go directly to the button's event handler instead of having to add code to the Page_Load function.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem using two `HiddenField`.

- Set the two HiddenField using js/jquery(as you prefer)
- Force the form submit in the js function(`form1.submit()`)
- In the formLoad check if the HiddenFields are empty. If no run your method and then clear the HiddenFields

Comment: +1 Thanks, the solution I used was similar in concept to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the __doPostBack function to post to server. just make sure you add a server control to the page so the function is inserted. here is a small example that you can customize for your needs:

aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Try1.WebForm1" EnableEventValidation="false"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#lblInvoke').hover(
                function () {
                    __doPostBack('<%= LinkButton1.ClientID %>', 'value1,value2');
                     }
                );
             });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <label id="lblInvoke">Hover This!</label>
        <br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" Style="display:none;">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Try1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string passedArgument = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT");
            string[] paramsArray = passedArgument.Split(',');
            Label1.Text = string.Format("Returned from server. params: {0},{1}", paramsArray[0], paramsArray[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you add the EnableEventValidation="false" attribute to page.

Comment: +1 I managed to figure this out a few minutes before you posted it. I did have one improvement: I pass the arguments as a JSON object to avoid needing to parse a string.

Comment: I saw you did the minute I posted myself...the JSON stuff is sure more elegant.