# Wait popup response before C# function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, alertify

I'm trying to call a JavaScript function with a popup, and if user click on "Ok", it calls a C# function. But the page always PostBack in same time I am loading the JavaScript function.

My HTML ASP:Button :

```
<asp:Button ID="PrchBtn" runat="server" class="PrchBtn" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, WebEDI_Save %>" OnClick="PrchBtn_Click" OnClientClick = "Confirm();" />
```

OnClientClick, it calls this JS function :

```
function Confirm() {
    var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
    confirm_value.type = "hidden";
    confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";

    alertify.confirm('<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource","WebEDI_PDF_MsgBox") %>', function (e) {
        if (e) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    });
}
```

And then my C# function :

```
public void PrchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Code here...
    }
```

It's working with a simple "confirm" dialog. But I want to custom the popup that's why I use "Alertify" library.

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE (See comments #3) :**
By following this link ([Call Code Behind Function from JavaScript (not AJAX!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865904/call-code-behind-function-from-javascript-not-ajax))
This is my actual code :

```
<asp:Button ID="PrchBtn" runat="server" class="PrchBtn" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, WebEDI_Save %>" OnClientClick="Confirm(); return false;" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="PrchBtnHidden" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="PrchBtn_Click" style="display:none;" />

function Confirm() {
    var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
    confirm_value.type = "hidden";
    confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";

    alertify.confirm('<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource","WebEDI_PDF_MsgBox") %>', function (e) {
        if (e) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
            __doPostBack('<%= PrchBtnHidden.UniqueID %>');
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
            __doPostBack('<%= PrchBtnHidden.UniqueID %>');
        }
    });
}
```

But the problem is the same, JS and C# are doing stuff at the same time.

**UPDATE (Bonus bug) :**
I don't know why but my alertify is bugged.
On a prompt :

```
alertify.prompt("Message", function (e, str) {
        // str is the input text
        if (e) {
            Console.Log("Ok");
        } else {
            Console.Log("No");
        }
    }, "Default Value");
```

When I click on Ok or No, nothing is firing. And the TextBox content of the prompt is :

> function (e, str) {            // str is the input text            if (e) {                Console.Log("Ok");            } else {                Console.Log("No");            }        }

And with an Alertify.Confirm

```
alertify.confirm('<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource","WebEDI_PDF_MsgBox") %>', function (e) {
        if (e) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
            __doPostBack('<%= PrchBtnHidden.UniqueID %>');
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
            __doPostBack('<%= PrchBtnHidden.UniqueID %>');
        }
    });
```

Only "Ok" is firing. The cancel button does nothig.

**SOLUTION :**
Took another alertify.js (http://alertifyjs.com/)
And this is my JS function :

```
alertify.confirm('<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource","WebEDI_PDF_MsgBox") %>', function () {
        confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        __doPostBack('<%= PrchBtnHidden.UniqueID %>');
    },
      function () {
          confirm_value.value = "No";
          document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
          __doPostBack('<%= PrchBtnHidden.UniqueID %>');
      }).set('labels', { ok: 'Ok', cancel: 'No' });
```

And it works !

Comment: This is going to be tricky to do. Since your `Confirm()` function won't know at the end of its execution or not whether to cancel the postback or not, you'll need to prevent the postback there, then manually trigger the postback in the event handler for your `alertify`. Or if I were you, I'd take the opportunity to eliminate the postback and replace it with an AJAX call to a [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Comment: Is there a simple way to do it ? I tryied to call only the JS and a return false on the button. Then in my JS function, it will call a C# method. But the problem is this method needs to be static...

Comment: See the accepted answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865904/call-code-behind-function-from-javascript-not-ajax) for how to trigger a postback from JS and target a specific C# event handler.

Comment: I updated my first post with a new try (using your link). But not working too. :/

Comment: You need to `return false;` from your `Confirm()` function to prevent the postback from happening when that function completes.

Comment: Okay forgot this return. So now when I press the button, it calls JS. Then JS is calling C# but only when the button "OK" is pressed. The "Cancel" button don't call anything.

Comment: Done. I don't understand why but when I click on Cancel, C# is not called.

Comment: I'm betting the reason it doesn't proceed when you click No has something to do with how alertify processes the No response for an `alertify.confirm`.  Try using `alertify.prompt` as described [here](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/) (note the different arguments)

Comment: So yes my alertify is bugged. With the "confirm" example on Alertify doc, only the Ok is firing.
With prompt, nothing is firing, and the textbox content is my alertify function.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with alertify to help much further at the moment. If you add your alertify.prompt code to your question, I may be able to install alertify on my system tonight and try debugging that way.

Comment: Updated my first post. I'm novice in JS and not able to find the problem.

Comment: I don't have time at the moment to actually play with your code at the moment, I'll try later. I will say that I think everything looks good, so my guess is that alertify works different than we expect. I usually use [jQuery Noty](http://ned.im/noty/#/about) by the way, it's similar to `alertify`. You might want to experiment with it.

Comment: Found a solution with another alertify.js file. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Make sure you post your solution as an answer so others will know what to do if they run into the same problem.

Comment: Don't post your solution in your question! Put it in a separate answer post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Solution :***
Create 2 HTML buttons, one visible linked to the JavaScript function and another not visible linked to the C# method :

```
<asp:Button ID="PrchBtn" runat="server" class="PrchBtn" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, WebEDI_Save %>" OnClientClick="Confirm(); return false;" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="PrchBtnHidden" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="PrchBtn_Click" style="display:none;" />
```

The JS :

```
function Confirm() {
    var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
    confirm_value.type = "hidden";
    confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";

    alertify.confirm('<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource","WebEDI_PDF_MsgBox") %>', function () {
        confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        __doPostBack('<%= PrchBtnHidden.UniqueID %>');
    },
      function () {
          confirm_value.value = "No";
          document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
          __doPostBack('<%= PrchBtnHidden.UniqueID %>');
      }).set('labels', { ok: 'Ok', cancel: 'No' });
}
```

When you will click on the 1st button, it will call JS. Then JS will call the PostBack of the second button.
And I had a problem with Alertify, so I used another source : http://alertifyjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger click on hidden buttons where you can have attached click handlers on code behind.

Server:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrchBtnHiddenNo.Click += PrchBtnHiddenNo_Click;
            PrchBtnHiddenYes.Click += PrchBtnHiddenYes_Click;
        }

        void PrchBtnHiddenYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void PrchBtnHiddenNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Client:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <script src="Scripts/alertify.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/alertify.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/alertify.core.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <hgroup class="title">
        <h1>Test alertify</h1>
    </hgroup>


    <asp:Button ID="PrchBtn" runat="server" class="PrchBtn" Text="Click Here" OnClientClick="Confirm(); return false;" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="PrchBtnHiddenYes" ClientIDMode="Static" Style="display: none;" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="PrchBtnHiddenNo" ClientIDMode="Static" Style="display: none;" />
    <script>
        function Confirm() {
            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";

            alertify.confirm('Do it', function (e) {
                if (e) {
                    $('#PrchBtnHiddenYes').click();
                    confirm_value.value = "Yes";

                } else {
                    $('#PrchBtnHiddenNo').click();
                    confirm_value.value = "No";                    
                }
            });
        }
    </script>    
</asp:Content>
```

JS Source and css downloaded from: http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/

Important Note: If you are trying to trigger click on file upload input IE for sore will not let u do that.

You can use pure java script no jquery:

```
document.getElementById("PrchBtnHiddenYes").click();
```